# How to swap orbitals in ORCA?

Tags: software, orca, pdynamo, charmm, qmmm

I am trying to swap orbitals for a high-spin iron(IV) complex. The orbitals that correspond to the iron are not in any of the SOMOs.

I am using the pDynamo QM/MM program, which is an interface for CHARMM and ORCA. Does anyone know the correct formatting to swap orbitals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the correct formatting. The section defining the QM needs to have the `MORead` option, the `%moinp` section, and the `%scf` section. Example:

```
!B3LYP 6-31G* Slowconv MOREAD
*xyz 0 3
...
*

%moinp "01.ethylene.gbw"
 %scf
  rotate {7, 8, 90, 0, 0}
 end
end
```